# Pandas Dataframe merge on two different key to get original data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, join

Question title might be confusing but here is the example of what I intends to perform.

Below is one the main dataframe with request data

```
d = {'ID':['A1','A2','A3','A4'],'ID2': ['B1','B2','B3','B4'],'B':[-1,5,6,7000],'ExtD':['CA','CB','CC','CD']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Now, Response might be based on ID or ID2 column and looks like this -

```
d = {'RetID':['A1','A2','B3','B4'],'C':[1.3,5.4,4.5,1.3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2
```

where RetID could be ID or ID2 from the request along with additional data C. Once response is received I need to merge it back with original dataframe to get data ExtD.

the solution I have come up with is to do -

```
df2 = df2.merge(df[['ID','ExtD',]],'left',left_on=['RetID'],right_on=['ID'])
df2 = df2.merge(df[['ID2','ExtD']],'left',left_on=['RetID'],right_on=['ID2'],suffixes = ('_d1','_d2'))
df2.rename({'ExtD_d1':'ExtD'},axis=1,inplace=True)
df2.loc[df2['ExtD'].isnull(),'ExtD'] = df2['ExtD_d2']
df2.drop({'ID2','ExtD_d2'},axis=1,inplace=True)
```

so expected output is,

```
res = {'RetID':['A1','A2','B3','B4'],'C':[1.3,5.4,4.5,1.3],'ExtD':['CA','CB','CC','CD']}
df2= pd.DataFrame(data=res)
df2
```

EDIT2: updated requirement tweak.

```
res = {'RetID':['A1','A2','B1','B2'],'C':[1.3,5.4,4.5,1.3],'ExtD':['CA','CB','CC','CD'],'ID':['A1','A2','A3','A4'],'ID2': ['B1','B2','B3','B4']}
```

Is there an efficient way to do this ? There might be more than 2 IDs - ID, ID2, ID3 and more than one column to join from the reqest dataframe. TIA.

EDIT: Fixed the typo.

Comment: Please, can you explain why for B1 & B2 the ExtID is CC & CD (and not CA & CB)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `melt` to transform your first dataframe then `merge` with the second:

```
tmp = df.melt('ExtD', value_vars=['ID', 'ID2'], value_name='RetID')
df2 = df2.merge(tmp[['ExtD', 'RetID']])
```

```
>>> df2
  RetID    C ExtD
0    A1  1.3   CA
1    A2  5.4   CB
2    B1  4.5   CA
3    B2  1.3   CB

>>> tmp
  ExtD variable RetID
0   CA       ID    A1
1   CB       ID    A2
2   CC       ID    A3
3   CD       ID    A4
4   CA      ID2    B1
5   CB      ID2    B2
6   CC      ID2    B3
7   CD      ID2    B4
```

**Update**

> What if I need to merge ID and ID2 columns as well?

```
df2 = df2.merge(df[['ID', 'ID2', 'ExtD']], on='ExtD')
```

```
>>> df2
  RetID    C ExtD  ID ID2
0    A1  1.3   CA  A1  B1
1    A2  5.4   CB  A2  B2
2    B3  4.5   CC  A3  B3
3    B4  1.3   CD  A4  B4
```

Comment: Perfect. will mark this as solution. Thanks.

Comment: what if I need to merge ID and ID2 columns as well? 
```
res = {'RetID':['A1','A2','B1','B2'],'C':[1.3,5.4,4.5,1.3],'ExtD':['CA','CB','CC','CD'],'ID':['A1','A2','A3','A4'],'ID2': ['B1','B2','B3','B4']}
```

Comment: Now this is the proper use case for `melt`